# Invariant metric of a matrix Lie Group as induced metric in R^(n^2)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I was wondering if a for a matrix Lie group, an invariant metric can in general be thought of as the induced Metric of the group's submanifold in $\mathbb{R^n}^2$. This seems to line up for simple examples.

For example, in $U(1) = SO(2)$, the submanifold traces out a circle parameterized by the angle of rotation.* Also, in $SU(2)$, the submanifold can be thought of as the 3 sphere in $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R^4}$ if we [think of $S^3$ as the group of unit quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Group_structure), which gives us embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that preserves the metric under the group action (i.e. multiplication by a unit quaternion as being a rotation in this 4d space).**

My question is does this notion of invariant measure as this induced metric carry over to all matrix Lie groups?

*,**: Clarification

I'm leaving out a detail, since for both the matrix representation of SO(2), $\theta \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
    cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\
    -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

and the (complex 2D) representation of SU(2) via quaternions
$x_1 + x_2 i + x_3 j + x_4 k \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 + x_2 i & x_3 + x_4 i \\
    -x_3 + x_4 i & x_1 - x_2 i \\
\end{bmatrix}$

The first column traces out the desired shape, which is a circle in $\mathbb{R^2}$ for $SO(2)$ and a 3-sphere in $\mathbb{R^4} = \mathbb{C^2}$ for SU(2). Then for both groups, the second column traces out the same shape in the second half of the coordinates. This means the metric on the group given by these maps is still the circle or 3-sphere metric multiplied by 2, roughly speaking. These are both still preserved by the group action.

EDIT****: I believe this doesn't work in general (see below comments) but does for unitary matrices. Note that the inner product of two matrices $A$ and $B$ is given by $d(A,B) = Tr(A^t B)$. So if we have a unitary matrix, U and consider the action L_U. Then $d(L_U (A), L_U (B)) = Tr((UA)^t(UB)) = Tr(A^t U^t U B) = Tr(A^t B) = d(A,B)$ since $U^t U = Id$. So the metric is invariant under the group action if the group is unitary.

Comment: Well I think there will always be an embedding into some Euclidean space that is an isometry, but that's not really an interesting algebraic fact because it doesn't have anything to do with the group structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Consider a (say, left-)invariant metric $g$ on $\textrm{GL}(n, \Bbb R)$, which has the canonical natural embedding as an open subset into the space $M(n, \Bbb R) \cong \Bbb R^{n^2}$ of $n \times n$ matrices. Since $g$ is left-invariant, for all $A \in \textrm{GL}(n, \Bbb R)$, the left translation map $L_A : X \mapsto AX$ is an isometry of $g$, but we may identify the tangent map $T_I L_A$ at the identity $I$ with $A$ itself. Do the dilation maps, i.e., those corresponding to $A = \lambda I$, preserve the metric induced by the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^{n^2}$?

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing not since the inner product of two vectors would be scaled by $\lambda^2$ under this map. Maybe another question would be if it is true for unitary groups, such as the ones I mentioned above? I'm thinking this would probably be true since a unitary matrix preserves the norm of vectors. But I'm having trouble thinking about this in terms of vectors in the tangent space of the lie group.

Comment: If we think of a matrix $X \in T_A \textrm{GL}(n, \Bbb R)$ as a sequence $[X_1 \,\cdots\, X_n]$ of column vectors $X_a \in \Bbb R^n$, then $T_I L_B \leftrightarrow B$ acts as $X \mapsto [BX_1\,\cdots\,BX_n]$. In particular, $B$ always preserves the lengths of column vectors w.r.t. the Euclidean norm, and hence of matrices $X$ iff $B\in\textrm{O}(n,\Bbb R)$ (the orthogonal group of the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n$). In particular, your embedding of $\textrm{SU}(2)$ can be regarded as factoring through $\textrm{O}(4,\Bbb R)$, which explains why this property holds for that group and embedding.

Comment: NB, though, that there is more than one way to embed a copy of $\textrm{O}(n, \Bbb R)$ into $M(n, \Bbb R)$, and that there is more than one left-invariant metric on $\textrm{O}(n, \Bbb R)$, and these are not generally compatible with the usual Euclidean metric. So to make a precise statement one must specify the situation precisely. This remark is thus dual in a sense to Matt Samuel's above comment in reply to the question.